# How to fix non integer error, when testing for non-integers entered by input

Tags: python, python-2.7

Trying to finish a small school assignment program, need to finish it by testing for non-int and showing error, and ask for int answers.
(Very basic and yet i'm still struggling)

`int(input"..."))` needs "base 10" and doesn't allow error for non-integer inputs

```py
num1 = input("Please input your first integer: ")
num2 = input("Please input your second integer: ")
#if type(num1) == int and type(num2) == int:

if isinstance(num1,int) and isinstance(num2,int):
    pass
else:
    print("You must enter a number (i.e. 0,1,2...)")
num3 = (num1 * num2)
print("The product of those numbers is: ")
print((str(num3) + ' ') * num3)
if input('Do you want to go again? (y/n) ') == 'n':
    exit
```

Line 14, `num3 = (num1 * num2)` can't multiply 'str'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

input returns a string by default.

Add these to your code  after the first two lines:

```
print(type(num1), type(num2))
print(isinstance(num1, int), isinstance(num1, str))
```

To see the problem.

You can try alternatively:

```
if num1.isdigit() and num2.isdigit():
  pass
```

instead of isinstance()

Remember that when you perform the arithmetic operations later on you will need to convert these to integers from strings

Answer (score 0):

I think you can convert the input variables to "int" type if it is int number, and catch the exception.

```
try:
   num1 = int(num1)
except ValueError,e:
   print(e)
```